# Is there an analog of swagger ui for OpenRPC?

Tags: json-rpc

Is there a tool that can visualise OpenRPC json documents to HTML, like swagger ui for OpenAPI json or yaml documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an official tool ([OpenRPC Playground](https://github.com/open-rpc/playground)), which includes an editor and a live-preview of the documentation, and there is the [OpenRPC Playground online](https://playground.open-rpc.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I do not know such a tool. OpenRPC is not very much adopted. I would suggest you to use JSight (https://jsight.io). It has json-rpc support, and also extremely simple language (much better, than OpenRPC or similar languages). Here you can see [comparison between OpenRPC and JSight](https://jsight.io/docs/api-examples/example08).

E.g. API spec may look like this:

```
JSIGHT 0.3

URL /json-rpc-endpoint
  Protocol json-rpc-2.0

  Method subtract
    Params
      [
        123, // first param
        232  // second param
      ]
    Result
      -109 // subtraction result
```

And you'll get the documentation like [this](https://editor.jsight.io/r/bj2k7Lw/1).